# How can I Schedule mail using java Spring MVC

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc

I have created an application in which I want to add schedule mail feature. I have created application using Java spring MVC. Is there a way to schedule mail using Java spring. I want to send mail 24 hours before the event is occured.

Comment: You might want to look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511965/scheduling-task-in-spring-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511965/scheduling-task-in-spring-java)

Comment: are you after help in scheduling or help in mail sending or both? Whichever it may be, there are already threads about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job with using the `@Scheduled` annotation. Every job's tick (for example, every day at 6 AM) you can check which messages are ready to be sent and then send them. Don't forget also to add the `@EnableScheduling` annotation in your config.

```
@Component
public class MailSenderJob {

   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 6 * * ?")
   public void execute() {
      ...
      send(messages);
    }
}
```

For more information about scheduling check the [Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) guide.