# Call Java method based on date passing in database column

Tags: java, database, spring

Let's assume we have a database table (a JPA entity), which is created as follows

```
id|start_date         |end_date           |object_id
1 |2018-01-01 00:00:00|2018-07-01 20:00:00|1
```

I would like to run a specific method when end_date passes current_date() - and I want Spring/Java/DB to start that method, without using schedulers. Some pseudo code below:

```
when (end_date <= current_date()) -> myClass.executeMyMethod(object_id)
```

Is this even possible? I've searched through a lot of different sites and am yet to find an answer.

Edit - here is an entity for which I would like to do that:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "time_based_event", schema = "timing")
public class TimePassingByTrigger {

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    protected LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "endDate", nullable = false)
    protected LocalDateTime endDate; 

    @Column(name = "object_id", nullable = false)
    protected Long objectId; 

}
```

And for service call - let's assume that I would like to do something like:

```
public class TimeFiredEvent {

    // this method should be executed for each objectId for
    // which end_date has passed
    public void thisShouldRunOnlyWhenDatePasses(Long objectId) {
        System.out.println("Time has passed for object: " + objectId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide us at least the entity mapping and the service calls.

Comment: @Nikolas updated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Also I don't see how this is going to be done in Java level without the use of a 'scheduled' thread. More importantly though, we don't you want to use some kind of scheduling?

Comment: Most important reason for that it shouldn't be based on scheduling is that I need the thisShouldRunOnlyWhenDatePasses call as close as possible to the endDate in the database - even a one second delay is a big amount here.

Comment: Using a scheduler or a job scheduler will not give you a 'one second delay'.

Comment: Using ScheduledExecutorService, set delay = theDateYouWant.getTime() - new Date().getTime()

Comment: Spring [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html)?  See Question, [*Scheduling Task in Spring/Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511965/642706)

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` class does *not* represent a specific moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. You likely want the `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may **want** is an `EntityListener`

```
@Table(name="time_based_event", schema="timing")
@EntityListeners(class=TimeFiredEvent.class)
public class TimePassingByTrigger {
....
```

And you define the actual listener

```
public class TimeFiredEvent {
    @PostPersist
    public void checkTriggerTime(TimePassingByTrigger trig) {
       if(trig.getEndDate().before(new Date()) {
         thisShouldRunOnlyWhenDatePasses(trig.getId());
       }
    }

    public void thisShouldRunOnlyWhenDatePasses(Long objectId) {
    }
}
```

However, this is probably not what you actually **need**.  An EntityListener is only going to execute when the entity is saved, retrieved, or deleted. (The valid callback points are `@PrePersist`, `@PreRemove`, `@PostPersist`, `@PostRemove`, `@PreUpdate`, `@PostUpdate`, `@PostLoad`)

But there is no mechanism for executing code just because time has continued its inexorable march forward.  You will still have to have some kind of polling mechanism or a sleeping Java thread if you want to do a check at other times.

Comment: Thanks, but as you've pointed out - this is not what I need, as entities do not change, so no callbacks will be fired. Thanks anyways.